# 'C' appearing as 2 different values?

Tags: c, assembly, att, cmp

I'm trying to compare 2 different char in assembly(calling assembly function in C program). One of the char belongs to a struct and the other is passed in when calling the function.

```
struct node {
    void   *previous;       
    void   *next;   
    unsigned int num;       
    unsigned int A;     
    unsigned int B;
}

node something;
something.A = 'C'; //assume everything else is correct

char A = 'C';
int func( char A ){ }:
find_course:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $28, %esp
    movl    8(%ebp), %ebx
    movl    10(%ebp), %ecx
    movl    16(%ebp), %edx
    movl    something, %edi
    cmpl    10(%edi), %ebx

.END:
    leave
    ret
```

when I debug with gdb, %ebx is 83 whereas 10(%edi) is 21315. If I print them out as characters, both appear to be 'C'. Is there any way that I can convert 21315 to 83?

Comment: What are the parameters to find_course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: you want to use `movb 10(%edi), %al` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You're just having some data-interpretation problems.  Check out the hex values of the numbers you're dealing with:

```
 Base 10      Base 16
   83           53
  21315        5343
```

As you can see, the first byte there is `53` in both cases.  You just are happening to read more than just one byte everywhere - that's what the `l` suffixes on your instructions mean.  You probably want to read less than than that.

Comment: Urmmmm, what am I suppose to do here? I don't really understand.

Comment: @user1043625 you're supposed to learn about data types and bit width of integers.